# Laravel ajax post data

Tags: javascript, ajax, laravel

I have an eCommerce shop where I have to filter products by its categories.

I have to post an array of all filters in the controller, but I am getting this error

```
 "message": "",
    "exception": "Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel\\Exception\\NotFoundHttpException",
    "file": "C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\web_front\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\RouteCollection.php",
    "line": 179
```

Here is my code:

```
 <script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var categories = [];
        $('input[name="cat[]"]').on('change', function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            categories = []; // reset
            $('input[name="cat[]"]:checked').each(function()
            {
                categories.push($(this).val());
            });



            $.ajax({

                type:"GET",

                url:'advanced_filter/' + categories,


                success:function(data){

                    console.log(data);
                },
                error: function(xhr,errmsg,err)
                {
                    console.log(xhr.responseText);
                }
            });
        });
    });

</script>
```

web.php

```
Route::get('advanced_filter/{filters}', 'HomepageController@advanced_filter')->name('advanced_filter');


 public function advanced_filter($filters)
    {
dd($filters);
}
```

I am trying to show all the filters, so I can make a query to get all the products based on filters. I have created the script where I get all filters and want to post it in the controller.  Please, can you see this? Thank you

Comment: You do not seem to be sending GET parameters to the route and controller

Comment: @kelvin what should I do ??

Comment: Where you have defined `$request`in your method ? it should be `public function advanced_filter(Request $request){dd($request->filters);}`

Comment: Your routes should have be something like Route::get('advanced_filter/{filters}'...
Make sure to also define $request by calling Request facade.

Comment: I changed that... but it shows the same errorr

Comment: You may missing a starting `/` before your URL

Answer (score 0):

first of all :

```
"exception":"Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel\\Exception\\NotFoundHttpException",
```

above exeption occur when route is not found . NotFoundHttpException has status 404

in your code you are passing array of categories in route params , which is syntactically wrong , so thats why failed to find route .

```
Route::get('advanced_filter', 'HomepageController@advanced_filter')->name('advanced_filter');
```

from frontend side : pass categories as query parameters

url will be :

> /advanced_filter?queryParameter= ids of selected categories

`/advanced_filter?categories=1,3,7`

your ajax function will be :

```
$.ajax({
     type:"GET",
     url:`/advanced_filter?categories=${categories.join(',')}`,
     success:function(data){
             console.log(data);
      },
      error: function(xhr,errmsg,err){
             console.log(xhr.responseText);
      }
   });
```

in your controller :

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

public function advanced_filter(Request $request)
{
    $filter_categories=[];
    if($request->has('categories')){
      $filter_categories=$request->query('categories');
    }

    /* you can pass extra query parameter like sortBy,sortOrder,limit  in url 
     `/advanced_filter?categories=1,3,7&limit=24&sortBy=name&sortOrder=desc`
 */

     $sortBy=$request->has('sortBy')?$request->query('sortBy'):'id';
     $sortOrder=$request->has('sortOrder')?$request->query('sortOrder'):'desc';
     $limit = $request->has('limit')?$request->has('limit'):12;

     /* assuming you have models with relations */

     $query = Products::query();
     $query->with('categories');
     if(count($filter_categories)>0){
        $query->whereHas('categories', function ($q) use ($filter_categories) {
            $q->whereIn('categories.id',$filter_categories);
        });
     }
     $query->orderBy($sortBy,$sortOrder);
     $products = $query->paginate($limit);
     return response()->json($products);

}
```